# -70 reputation for no apparent reason

Tags: support, reputation

Could someone take a look at my (main user) profile and shed some light on the 70 reputation that went missing today? It simply states "user was removed". Thank you!

Comment: This [MSE thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126471/214632) may provide some more up-to-date information than the linked meta.math.SE thread, but the basic idea is the same. An account was deleted (without too many votes), and the total amount of reputation that user had given you was 70.

Comment: If it makes you feel better I lost 200. Sad, but such things happen.

Comment: I was a bit curious so I did a bit of digging. Most people at the top lost quite a bit except Amy, Lab and Ron. Matt E and Mariano lost over 300 and Georges lost over 1000 points. Looks like whoever was removed was heavily into algebra/algebraic geometry.

Comment: [*Looks like whoever was removed was heavily into algebra/algebraic geometry.*]
Agreed.
I lost 506.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen [removed user](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/38268/fpqc)... I am surprised that the SE team did not keep the user's votes: 4003 up and 1659 down.

Comment: @ArthurFischer: The data above means that the deleted user
had given enough votes to make it to the first page of all time voters. Looks like the bar for not removing the votes is quite high!?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The process for determining that the special deletion procedure is used seems to be rather improvised. It has happened before that the SE employee deleting the user missed that the user had a large amount of votes.

Comment: @MadScientist Did they ever un-delete the votes after recognizing the mistake?

Comment: It seems to me that when a user is deleted, her upvotes should not be necessarily be deleted, unless her upvotes are the reason for deletion. Perhaps too complicated for a program!

Comment: @AndréNicolas Most deletions are at user's own request (I guess this one was too), and they are handled manually by the SE team. So it's more of a policy issue than a programming issue. The most upvoted feature request in the history of SE is [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125740/), and it's neither declined nor implemented fully.

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY yes, they have done that at least once. It was a more drastic example though because it was on a beta site where the average rep is lower, and the impact of deleting many votes higher.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks; here is [another example of reversal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173699/), on SO. I dropped a note to the SE team asking for the votes to be undeleted, based on the stats. He was in the top 0.03% of voters...

Comment: Was this just overturned? I received an unexplained 200 rep out of thin air, and this was the first thing that occured to me as a possible explanation.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes. About an hour ago SE replied to my request with "These will be restored." The delayed response was probably due to their data center relocation. Interesting  that your and others' timelines still show reputation drop on May 30. This may be recalculated later. Or not.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It did get recalculated: the drop on May 30 is gone from the reputation timeline of the affected users.